# Model posts JSON data on "destroy" request

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, post, extjs

I am having the following issue, which I cannot seem to resolve, even searching the forums online yielded no useful hints.

I have the following code, which determines the first selected record in an Ext.Tree.Panel and sends a destroy request. However, a JSON object is posted instead of the expected name/value query string.

```
var record = this.getClientUserTree().getSelectedRecord();

record.destroy({
     scope: this,
     success: this.onDeleteUserSuccess,
     failure: this.onDeleteUserFailure
});
```

I am including the code for the corresponding model as well as that of the dispatched request.

```
Ext.define('Admin.model.Client', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['id', 'name', 'company', 'address', 'postal_code', 'city', 'country', 'phone', 'fax', 'note'],

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
            read: 'clientajax',
            destroy: 'clientajax/delete'
        },
        reader: {
           type: 'json',
           root: 'results'
       }
    }
});
```

Posted string in the request:

```
{"id":"14","client":"5","username":"Testtest","firstName":"Genti","lastName":"Testing","role":"admin","superadmin":false}
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you for your help in advance,
Genti

Comment: Why is this wrong? It looks like you set up a reader that expects JSON and the posted string looks like a JSON string.

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure whether you understood what I meant. Maybe my explanation isn't very clear. The reader expects the response of the AJAX request to be JSON, which is correct and that's how it should be. However, when I issue a destroy request as above, the entire record data are POSTed as a JSON object to the destroy-URL (clientajax/delete above). However I expect it to be posted as a normal name/value query string (application/x-www-form-urlencoded), which in this case is not. I'm dying to figure out where is it that I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Ext.data.Model` destroy method uses the proxy's destroy method.

Unfortunately I've never found a non JSON or XML proxy in the ExtJS4 API. I've always used the `Ext.data.proxy.Server` [extraParams](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Server-cfg-extraParams) property to pass string value parameters to my server when I absolutely had to.

You could also try [extending the proxy to accommodate what you need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417007/extjs4-is-there-a-non-json-xml-writer-for-proxies) but I've never tried it.

With all that said, keep in mind that there are a great deal of libraries for parsing JSON or XML, it isn't too hard to integrate them on your server, you should take a look at that route also.

Comment: Thank you, after some further searching, I ended up parsing the posted JSON in the server side.